# what is the complexity of recursive summation

Tags: math, recursion, time-complexity, dynamic-programming, asymptotic-complexity

can someone tell me the exact complexity of this recursion ?
this is actually formula for below question ( solved in recursive brute force way )

> There is n steps stairs and a person standing at the bottom want to reach at top. Person can take max k steps at a time ( i.e. he can take 1, 2 , 3,.. upto k steps).Count how many ways person can climb the stairs.

[image]

Comment: A formula does not have a (time) complexity. Only an implementation does. Show your implementation and what you think the time complexity is.

Comment: Alternatively, if you're really just trying to better understand the formula, you may want to check in with [math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com)

Comment: thanks , i have posted same question there